# Value tail is not a member of (String, String)

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using Spark-shell.I have stored Tweets in Kafka topic to performing sentiment analysis using Spark-shell.

I have added Dependencies : 
org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.2
edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.5.1

These is the code on which i am working:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds 
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(5))
val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "sandbox.hortonworks.com:2181","test-consumer-group", Map("test12" -> 5))
val topCounts60 = kafkaStream.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60)).map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }.transform(_.sortByKey(false))
  topCounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val topList = rdd.take(10)
      println("\nPopular topics in last 60 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
      topList.foreach { case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }
    })
kafkaStream.count().map(cnt => "Received " + cnt + " kafka messages.").print()
val wordSentimentFilePath = "hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/TwitterData/AFINN.txt"
    val wordSentiments = ssc.sparkContext.textFile(wordSentimentFilePath).map { line =>
    val Array(word, happiness) = line.split("\t")
    (word, happiness)
    } cache()
val happiest60 = kafkaStream.map(hashTag => (hashTag.tail, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60)). transform{topicCount => wordSentiments.join(topicCount)}
                .map{case (topic, tuple) => (topic, tuple._1 * tuple._2)}.map{case (topic, happinessValue) => (happinessValue, topic)}.transform(_.sortByKey(false))
ssc.start()
ssc.stop()
```

But while executing these line,

```
val happiest60 = kafkaStream.map(hashTag => (hashTag.tail,1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60)). transform{topicCount => wordSentiments.join(topicCount)}.map{case (topic, tuple) => (topic, tuple._1 * tuple._2)}.map{case (topic, happinessValue) => (happinessValue, topic)}.transform(_.sortByKey(false))
```

It throws error:

> error : value tail is not a member of (String, String)

Comment: Try declaring types of all the variables. That might help you figure out where you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the type of hashTag is `(String, String)`, so the tail operation is not defined. `tail` is a function defined on collections, not on tuples.

`map` operation operates on a single item received from the stream. If the kafka stream contains items with type `(String, String)`, that's normal.